# Consecutive days to track purchases(return flag to another column?)

Tags: sql, oracle

In a dataset, there are users along with their purchases from different companies and the dates of these purchases. (Other columns are irrelevant for now.) I am trying to identify users and their purchase dates where the users developed a habit of ordering on consecutive days (from ONE company on multiple days is bad, ordering on different days from different company is OK)  rather than ordering everything at once to save on shipping costs, etc.

For example, if they ordered on 2023.08.23, 2023.08.24, and 2023.08.25 instead of ordering everything at once, i.e., on 2023.08.23, 2023.08.23, and 2023.08.23.

I tried running this code on my dataset. But it shows a different output, to what I wanted to see. Could you please fix my code?
Is it possible to mark somehow those days, users in the original table? That was my plan with the flags in my previously posted Code(for further investigation) - Image added.

[image]

```
WITH t2 AS (
    SELECT USERT, CREATIONDATE, COMPANY ,
    LAG(creationdate) OVER(PARTITION BY USERT ORDER BY USERT) AS prev_diff,
    LEAD(creationdate) OVER(PARTITION BY USERT ORDER BY USERT) AS next_diff,
    LAG(USERT) OVER(ORDER BY USERT) AS prev_USERT,
    LEAD(USERT) OVER(ORDER BY USERT) AS next_USERT
    FROM VEKPOLFA1P72_TESZT_P
)

SELECT USERT, CREATIONDATE, COMPANY,
       CASE
           WHEN ((prev_diff IS NULL OR creationdate - prev_diff <= 1) AND USERT = prev_USERT) OR 
                ((next_diff IS NULL OR next_diff - creationdate <= 1) AND USERT = next_USERT) THEN 'Consecutive'
           ELSE 'Non-Consecutive'
       END AS consecutive_marker
FROM t2
WHERE creationdate >= '20230601' AND creationdate <= '20230630'
```

Dataset example:

```
USERT;CREATIONDATE;COMPANY
43014502;20230605;SCHKFT
43014503;20230605;EURFT.
43014509;20230606;HORANS
43014516;20230607;EURFT.
43014516;20230607;EURFT.
43014522;20230620;HORANS
43014523;20230623;GHII K
43014524;20230624;EURFT.
43014533;20230603;HORANS
43014534;20230629;GHII K
45921390;20230629;NANREC
45921390;20230628;NANREC
45921390;20230630;NANREC
45931996;20230630;BEYECT
49117108;20230613;BEYECT
49148157;20230612;D E BT
49148163;20230612;STAFT.
49148165;20230615;MENFT.
49148165;20230615;MENFT.
49148167;20230604;INGMBH
49148167;20230605;INGMBH
49148167;20230606;INGMBH
49148168;20230601;GUT KG
49148174;20230620;PAPRT.
49148174;20230620;FRT.
49148174;20230620;PAPRT.
49148175;20230601;PANOPE
49148175;20230602;FAE
49148175;20230605;PANOPE
49148175;20230605;PANOPE
49148175;20230605;PANOPE
49148179;20230621;GK LGA
49148179;20230622;GK LGA
49148179;20230623;GK LGA
49148179;20230624;GK LGA
49148183;20230601;SCHMBH
49148183;20230601;SCHMBH
49148183;20230630;SCHMBH
```

Expected output:

```
USERT;CREATIONDATE;COMPANY
45921390;20230629;NANREC
45921390;20230628;NANREC
45921390;20230630;NANREC
49148167;20230604;INGMBH
49148167;20230605;INGMBH
49148167;20230606;INGMBH
49148179;20230621;GK LGA
49148179;20230622;GK LGA
49148179;20230623;GK LGA
49148179;20230624;GK LGA
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY usert
  ORDER     BY creationdate
  MEASURES
    CLASSIFIER() AS consecutive_marker
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ("Consecutive"{2,} | "Non-consecutive")
  DEFINE
    "Consecutive" AS PREV(creationdate) + INTERVAL '1' DAY >= creationdate
                  OR NEXT(creationdate) - INTERVAL '1' DAY <= creationdate
)
```

Or, in earlier versions:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       CASE
       WHEN LAG(creationdate)
              OVER (PARTITION BY usert ORDER BY creationdate, ROWNUM)
              + INTERVAL '1' DAY
              >= creationdate
       OR   LEAD(creationdate)
              OVER (PARTITION BY usert ORDER BY creationdate, ROWNUM)
              - INTERVAL '1' DAY
              <= creationdate
       THEN 'Consecutive'
       ELSE 'Non-consecutive'
       END AS consecutive_marker
FROM   table_name t
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (USERT, CREATIONDATE, COMPANY) AS
SELECT 43014502, DATE '2023-06-05', 'SCHKFT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43014503, DATE '2023-06-05', 'EURFT.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43014509, DATE '2023-06-06', 'HORANS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43014516, DATE '2023-06-07', 'EURFT.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43014516, DATE '2023-06-07', 'EURFT.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43014522, DATE '2023-06-20', 'HORANS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43014523, DATE '2023-06-23', 'GHII K' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43014524, DATE '2023-06-24', 'EURFT.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43014533, DATE '2023-06-03', 'HORANS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 43014534, DATE '2023-06-29', 'GHII K' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 45921390, DATE '2023-06-29', 'NANREC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 45921390, DATE '2023-06-28', 'NANREC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 45921390, DATE '2023-06-30', 'NANREC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 45931996, DATE '2023-06-30', 'BEYECT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49117108, DATE '2023-06-13', 'BEYECT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148157, DATE '2023-06-12', 'D E BT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148163, DATE '2023-06-12', 'STAFT.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148165, DATE '2023-06-15', 'MENFT.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148165, DATE '2023-06-15', 'MENFT.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148167, DATE '2023-06-04', 'INGMBH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148167, DATE '2023-06-05', 'INGMBH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148167, DATE '2023-06-06', 'INGMBH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148168, DATE '2023-06-01', 'GUT KG' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148174, DATE '2023-06-20', 'PAPRT.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148174, DATE '2023-06-20', 'FRT.'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148174, DATE '2023-06-20', 'PAPRT.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148175, DATE '2023-06-01', 'PANOPE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148175, DATE '2023-06-02', 'FAE'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148175, DATE '2023-06-05', 'PANOPE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148175, DATE '2023-06-05', 'PANOPE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148175, DATE '2023-06-05', 'PANOPE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148179, DATE '2023-06-21', 'GK LGA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148179, DATE '2023-06-22', 'GK LGA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148179, DATE '2023-06-23', 'GK LGA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148179, DATE '2023-06-24', 'GK LGA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148183, DATE '2023-06-01', 'SCHMBH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148183, DATE '2023-06-01', 'SCHMBH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 49148183, DATE '2023-06-30', 'SCHMBH' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| USERT | CREATIONDATE | CONSECUTIVE_MARKER | COMPANY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 43014502 | 2023-06-05 00:00:00 | Non-consecutive | SCHKFT |
| 43014503 | 2023-06-05 00:00:00 | Non-consecutive | EURFT. |
| 43014509 | 2023-06-06 00:00:00 | Non-consecutive | HORANS |
| 43014516 | 2023-06-07 00:00:00 | Consecutive | EURFT. |
| 43014516 | 2023-06-07 00:00:00 | Consecutive | EURFT. |
| 43014522 | 2023-06-20 00:00:00 | Non-consecutive | HORANS |
| 43014523 | 2023-06-23 00:00:00 | Non-consecutive | GHII K |
| 43014524 | 2023-06-24 00:00:00 | Non-consecutive | EURFT. |
| 43014533 | 2023-06-03 00:00:00 | Non-consecutive | HORANS |
| 43014534 | 2023-06-29 00:00:00 | Non-consecutive | GHII K |
| 45921390 | 2023-06-28 00:00:00 | Consecutive | NANREC |
| 45921390 | 2023-06-29 00:00:00 | Consecutive | NANREC |
| 45921390 | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | Consecutive | NANREC |
| 45931996 | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | Non-consecutive | BEYECT |
| 49117108 | 2023-06-13 00:00:00 | Non-consecutive | BEYECT |
| 49148157 | 2023-06-12 00:00:00 | Non-consecutive | D E BT |
| 49148163 | 2023-06-12 00:00:00 | Non-consecutive | STAFT. |
| 49148165 | 2023-06-15 00:00:00 | Consecutive | MENFT. |
| 49148165 | 2023-06-15 00:00:00 | Consecutive | MENFT. |
| 49148167 | 2023-06-04 00:00:00 | Consecutive | INGMBH |
| 49148167 | 2023-06-05 00:00:00 | Consecutive | INGMBH |
| 49148167 | 2023-06-06 00:00:00 | Consecutive | INGMBH |
| 49148168 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | Non-consecutive | GUT KG |
| 49148174 | 2023-06-20 00:00:00 | Consecutive | PAPRT. |
| 49148174 | 2023-06-20 00:00:00 | Consecutive | PAPRT. |
| 49148174 | 2023-06-20 00:00:00 | Consecutive | FRT. |
| 49148175 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | Consecutive | PANOPE |
| 49148175 | 2023-06-02 00:00:00 | Consecutive | FAE |
| 49148175 | 2023-06-05 00:00:00 | Consecutive | PANOPE |
| 49148175 | 2023-06-05 00:00:00 | Consecutive | PANOPE |
| 49148175 | 2023-06-05 00:00:00 | Consecutive | PANOPE |
| 49148179 | 2023-06-21 00:00:00 | Consecutive | GK LGA |
| 49148179 | 2023-06-22 00:00:00 | Consecutive | GK LGA |
| 49148179 | 2023-06-23 00:00:00 | Consecutive | GK LGA |
| 49148179 | 2023-06-24 00:00:00 | Consecutive | GK LGA |
| 49148183 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | Consecutive | SCHMBH |
| 49148183 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | Consecutive | SCHMBH |
| 49148183 | 2023-06-30 00:00:00 | Non-consecutive | SCHMBH |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-Spe3CsM)

Comment: Thank you! I am in my learning process in SQL, but im developing quickly and thanks to your answers below my Questions im always learning a tons from you! Please keep being so kind because it helps newbies a lot!